# How to find out the magic number for the .pyc header in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

Python bytecode (.pyc) files have a header that starts with a magic number that changes between Python versions. How can I (programmatically) find out that number for the current Python version in order to generate a valid header? I'm currently hard-coding the one for Python 3.7.1, but that means I now depend on a specific Python version.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8628185/149392) does exactly what I want using `py_compile.MAGIC`, but that does not seem to exist anymore in Python 3. How can I do the equivalent in Python 3?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
import dis
import marshal

PYC_HEADER = b'\x42\x0d\x0d\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

def f():
    print('Hello World')

with open('test.pyc', 'wb') as pyc:
    pyc.write(PYC_HEADER)
    marshal.dump(dis.Bytecode(f).codeobj, pyc)
```

This should create a file `test.pyc`, which can then be run, using the same Python interpreter as the script, and should print "Hello World!". And it does, but only when using Python 3.7. I'm looking for a way that generates the header for whichever version of Python 3 is used to run the script, rather than hard-coding 3.7.

For context:

I'm compiling a simple programming language to different bytecode formats (LLVM, Java bytecode, Web Assembly and now Python bytecode) as part of a planned tutorial series on compiler construction.

I can generate the Python bytecode using [the byteasm library](https://github.com/zachariahreed/byteasm), which gives me a function as a result. But in order to write the contents to a `.pyc` file, I need a valid header. By hard-coding the header, the code will only work if the people following the tutorial are running the same version of Python 3 as I am (3.7) or they'd have to manually find out the magic number for their version.

Comment: hey hows it goin. I really really want to see your tutorial series but i'm not too sure where I can find it. Could you pass me a link? Thanks friend

Comment: @Glubs I'm sorry to say I never got around to writing it. You can look at the code for the bytecode generator [here](https://github.com/sepp2k/minicomp/blob/master/src/main/python/bytecode_compiler.py), but be warned that there are barely any comments because I figured there's no need since I'd explain the code in the blog that I never ended up writing.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Python 3.4 there is the [`importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER) in the module `importlib`:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER.hex()
'420d0d0a'
```

Another solution for Python < 3.4 or Python2 is the [`get_magic` method of the `imp` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.get_magic).

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.get_magic().hex()
'420d0d0a'
```

Note, that while this still works in Python 3.7, it is deprecated since Python 3.4

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I needed (minus the `.hex()` since it should go into the file as bytes, not a hexstring).

Answer (score 9):

It has been [moved](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/14581d5dc4e4f9117e62b3a1bc62c4ba935be048) to [`importlib.util`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util):

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER
b'3\r\r\n'
```

[New in version 3.4.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.util)

Probably simplest to wrap this in a try/except to fall back to `py_compile`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual *integers* as written in [importlib source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L242-L478), you can use this:

```
>>> import importlib.util
>>> importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER
b'\xcb\r\r\n'
>>> [n] = struct.unpack("<H", importlib.util.MAGIC_NUMBER[:-2])
>>> n
3531
```

For example [3531](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b8664433829ea967c150363cf49a5c4c1380fe8/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L447) is the magic number for Python 3.12 final.

You can sanity check the value makes sense for your CPython version by checking in the ranges in [`PC/launcher.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5b8664433829ea967c150363cf49a5c4c1380fe8/PC/launcher.c#L1250-L1275).